# Loop mysql_fetch_assoc using foreach instead of a while loop

Tags: php

I have a mysql query:

```
$result = mysql_query("my query");
```

Is there a way to make something like this work?

```
$results = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); // fetch the results
```

And loop them using foreach instead of the classic while:

```
foreach($results as $result){
   $result1 = $result->result1;
   $result2 = $result->result2;
}
```

Ty

Comment: @mgraph Not using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) is one of the issues.

Comment: nope (too boring to write a complete answer, sorry)

Comment: could you explain why? the while technique works well for a reason... also you should look into pdo/mysqli!

Comment: Like said before, use PDO. Period.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Foreach is a construct that iterates arrays and objects.  `mysql_fetch_assoc` will return an array but each array will be only one row's worth of data. So your foreach will simply be giving you the columns present in the first row.

Save yourself from trouble, don't use mysql_fetch_assoc and foreach together.

Answer (score 3):

Because `mysql_fetch_assoc` only returns one row at a time, use it to convert the PHP result set into a PHP array. Then, use foreach on the array.

For example:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
     $rows[] = $row; 
} 

foreach($rows as $row) {
    //Then do something for each row, for e.g.:
    if ($row['col_name'] == 'somevalue'){
        $arrList[] = $row['id'];
    }
}
```

Or:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
     $rows[] = $row; 
} 

foreach($rows as $row) { 
     foreach($row as $field => $value) { 
          //do something with $field and $val 
     }
}
```

Or:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
     $rows[] = $row; 
} 

for($i=0;$i<count($rows);$i++) { 
     //do something with $rows[$i]['field_name'] 
}
```

Source:

[Devshed: PHP foreach/while mysql result?](http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/php-foreach-mysql-result-778824.html)

Comment: Don't use mysql (deprecated), use mysqli instead.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use mysql (deprecated), use mysqli instead.

```
$res = $mysqli->query($sql);
$rows = $res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach ($rows as $id => $rowData) {
    //do something with $rowData
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you have posted this answer here? There is no explanation. Your answer uses mysqli while the question was asking about `mysql_*`

Comment: I wanted to reply to cssyphus answer that mysql shouldn't be used and provided an example of foreach, as webmasters asked in question. I just added a comment.