# Looping throughout selected users and populating the drop-down list dynamically

Tags: php, html, mysqli

So this is a part from the administrator page.
After several modifications I came to this, which is the best I could get unfortunately:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT name
        FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

$users = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
     $users[] = $row["name"];
}

echo ('</br><form action="" method="POST" style="display:inline!important"></br>
        <select name="deleteUser">
        <option value="' . $users[1] . '">' . $users[1] . '</option>' . 
       '<option value="' . $users[2] . '">' . $users[2] . '</option>' .
       '<option value="' . $users[3] . '">' . $users[3] . '</option>' .
       '<option value="' . $users[4] . '">' . $users[4] . '</option>' .
       '<input class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-hover-green"  type="submit" value="Delete" name="delete"></select></form>');
if (isset($_POST["delete"]))
{
     $sql = "DELETE
             FROM users
             WHERE name = '" . $_POST["deleteUser"] . "'";
     mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

}
?>
```

I tried to write a loop to generate the select options like this:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT name
        FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

$users = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
     $users[] = $row["name"];
}

echo ('</br><form action="" method="POST" style="display:inline!important"></br>
        <select name="deleteUser">');

for ($i = 0; $i < count($users); $i++)
{
    echo('<option value="' . $users[$i] . '">' . $users[$i] . '</option>');
}   

echo('<input class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-hover-green"  type="submit" value="Delete"></select></form>');
if (isset($_POST["delete"]))
{
     $sql = "DELETE
             FROM users
             WHERE name = '" . $_POST["deleteUser"] . "'";
     mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

}
?>
```

But the browser doesn't render it(i.e Chrome), maybe because it just can't on portions? Like to wait for the loop to complete and then to end with the last part of the form.
Anyway, how could I make it work? Thanks mates...

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Maybe try with foreach ? like this `foreach(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) as $val) { echo '<option> '.$val["name"].' </option' }` please have a try with this way it might work. Your code quality is just really bad.

Comment: @Small developer Yeah it is. Thanks for the advice, it works.

Comment: @lalithkumar I was getting infinite loop, no errors, but now it works lol, i think because of the forgotten $ before i in the for definition area

Comment: I apparently don't have the ability to add this to the community wiki, so could we either make this an accepted answer or move it there?

Comment: Hey @udarH3 I'm creating an answer with that and you will approve that as it's correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `while` loop you can use `foreach` this is where you can use `foreach` properly

**Here is an example that might help you**

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
   $rows[] = $row; 
 }
foreach($rows as $val){

   //Here populate your options like this
   echo '<option> '.$val["name"].' </option'
}
```

Hope this will help you out :)

Comment: Please hit on Tick mark button to approve this answer as correct and if this useful to you then give a upvote thumb :)

Comment: Small developer:--> read this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621686/loop-mysql-fetch-assoc-using-foreach-instead-of-a-while-loop) then edit your answer, and after that i will up vote it

Comment: Excellent dude, it is perfect now :)