# How to display different rows from database with mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, rows

I'm trying to do something very basic but can't figure out how.

I'm trying to show one row of data from a table in my database, then in another section of the page i want to display the next row and so on

This is what I have at the moment which only displays the *first row* of my table

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM products";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
?>
Name:           <?=$row['vehicle']?><br/>
Description:    <?=$row['description']?><br/>
Price:          <?=$row['price']?><br/>
```

Comment: did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621686/loop-mysql-fetch-assoc-using-foreach-instead-of-a-while-loop

Comment: i dont understand this post